# How to add the index from list using cbind?

Tags: r

My data looks like :

```
lis=list(NULL, NULL, structure(c("A", "30", "5"), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
         c("Name", "M", "E") , "foo")), structure(c("B", "19", 
         "9"), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("Name", "M", "E"), "foo")))
```

Combine :

```
dat=do.call(cbind, lis)
```

Here I want to replace `foo` with the real correspondence (index from lis)

desired output :

```
       3      4 
 Name "A"  "B" 
 M    "30" "19"
 E    "5"  "9"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
as.data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), lis))
#     foo foo.1
#Name   A     B
#M     30    19
#E      5     9
```

Explanation: `Filter(Negate(is.null), lis)` removes `NULL` entries from your `list` prior to converting entries to a `data.frame`.

To replace column names with the index of the `list` entry do

```
setNames(
    data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), lis)), 
    which(sapply(lis, function(x) !is.null(x))))
#      3  4
#Name  A  B
#M    30 19
#E     5  9
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I asked for!   please see my desired output

Comment: @temor Isn't this exactly your expected output?

Comment: I meant to add the index   `[[3]]` and `[[4]]` as the column names.

Comment: @temor Ah I see; please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you would like the label the columns of `dat` to match how `lis` in indexed. However, `lis` has no names, just an automatic numbering that appears in output. You can simulate this using `seq_along` and filtering out the `NULL` elements:

```
colnames(dat) <- seq_along(lis)[!sapply(lis,is.null)]
dat
     3    4   
Name "A"  "B" 
M    "30" "19"
E    "5"  "9"
```

If `lis` did have names you can use `names(lis)` instead of the `seq_along`.